# Red-Gate SQL Compare and Powershell to run CDC script

Tags: powershell, redgate

Does Red-Gate SQL Compare need to be installed on On-Premise Database Server to run powershell scripts that are set for automation? I have Red-Gate on my local machine, and I am asking this question to figure out if i need to install it to server because that will determine if i need to buy another license.

Comment: Have you tried looking at their website? There's licensing details [here](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sc/getting-started/licensing/changes-to-distribution-of-command-line).

Answer (score 1):

There are subtleties in licensing that are best discussed in person with Redgate Sales. It will depend on whether you are the only user contributing to the database changes and triggering the automation, what 'user' will be running the automated process (is it you, or will it be drive by a service account?) If you contact sales@red-gate.com (or your Redgate account executive) they will be able to advise you on your options.